# I can't understand the following clojure.spec error

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I can't understand why the following spec error occurred.

Could anyone tell me why?

```clj
(ns spec-test 
   (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
             [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]))

;;; spec definitions

(s/def :msds.fontspec/tag #{:fontspec})

(s/def ::id string?)
(s/def ::size int?)
(s/def ::family string?)
(s/def ::color string?)

(s/def :msds.fontspec/attrs 
  (s/keys :req-un [::id ::size ::family ::color]))

(s/def :msds.fontspec/content (s/cat))

(s/def ::fontspec
  (s/keys :req-un [:msds.fontspec/tag :msds.fontspec/attrs :msds.fontspec/content]))

(s/def ::fontspecs (s/* ::fontspec))


;;; spec application

(defn transform-fontspecs
  [fontspecs]
  (->> fontspecs
       (map (fn [{:keys [attrs] :as fontspec}]
              [(get attrs :id) (dissoc attrs :id)] ))
       (into {}) ))

(s/fdef transform-fontspecs
  :args (s/cat :fontspec ::fontspecs))

(stest/instrument `transform-fontspecs)


;;; test code

(def test-sample
  '({:tag :fontspec,
     :attrs {:id "283f1EV", :size 21, :family "c2S6", :color ""},
     :content ()}
    {:tag :fontspec,
     :attrs
     {:id "BzYMt4eEm", :size -5, :family "q0xhOE3", :color "bhV3PsVh"},
     :content ()}
    {:tag :fontspec,
     :attrs {:id "uA2i", :size -5, :family "HHGoD", :color "J47ZX935"},
     :content ()}))

(transform-fontspecs test-sample)
```

The following is the error descriptions.

```
2. Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
   Error compiling src/spec_test.clj at (55:1)
   #:clojure.error{:phase :compile-syntax-check,
                   :line 55,
                   :column 1,
                   :source "/home/philos/work/metapdf/src/spec_test.clj"}
             Compiler.java: 7648  clojure.lang.Compiler/load
                      REPL:    1  metapdf.core/eval19243
                      REPL:    1  metapdf.core/eval19243
             Compiler.java: 7177  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7132  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3214  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3210  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  368  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   79  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  142  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               session.clj:  171  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
               session.clj:  170  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               Thread.java:  748  java.lang.Thread/run

1. Caused by clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
   Spec assertion failed.

         Spec: #object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509 0x3660c4ee "clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509@3660c4ee"]
        Value: (({:tag :fontspec,
                  :attrs {:id "283f1EV", :size 21, :family "c2S6", :color ""},
                  :content ()}
                 {:tag :fontspec,
                  :attrs
                  {:id "BzYMt4eEm", :size -5, :family "q0xhOE3", :color "bhV3PsVh"},
                  :content ()}
                 {:tag :fontspec,
                  :attrs {:id "uA2i", :size -5, :family "HHGoD", :color "J47ZX935"},
                  :content ()}))

     Problems: 

            val: ({:tag :fontspec,
                   :attrs {:id "283f1EV", :size 21, :family "c2S6", :color ""},
                   :content ()}
                  {:tag :fontspec,
                   :attrs
                   {:id "BzYMt4eEm", :size -5, :family "q0xhOE3", :color "bhV3PsVh"},
                   :content ()}
                  {:tag :fontspec,
                   :attrs {:id "uA2i", :size -5, :family "HHGoD", :color "J47ZX935"},
                   :content ()})
             in: [0]
         failed: map?
           spec: :spec-test/fontspec

                 alpha.clj:  132  clojure.spec.test.alpha/spec-checking-fn/conform!
                 alpha.clj:  140  clojure.spec.test.alpha/spec-checking-fn/fn
               RestFn.java:  408  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
             spec_test.clj:   55  spec-test/eval19293
             spec_test.clj:   55  spec-test/eval19293
             Compiler.java: 7177  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7636  clojure.lang.Compiler/load
                      REPL:    1  metapdf.core/eval19243
                      REPL:    1  metapdf.core/eval19243
             Compiler.java: 7177  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7132  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3214  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3210  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  368  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   79  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  142  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               session.clj:  171  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
               session.clj:  170  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
       .lang.Thread/run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the `Problems` part where it says `val` and `failed: map?`. 
The problem is that you're using regex operations like `s/*` which, when nested, sort of flattens the structure so it's expecting a map rather than a collection.
You should just use `coll-of` here, imho.
See https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_collections
Also the `:msds.fontspec/content` spec should probably be updated to not use `cat` but just `vector?` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solved my question.

One more question.

The spec of :msds.fontspec/content needs an empty list. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Then consider upvoting :)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but sadly the message says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."